# Fourier transform commute with partial derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-derivative, fourier-transform

Let $\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$, $\phi=\phi(x,y)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $y\in\mathbb{R}$, let $\mathcal{F}$ the Fourier transform wrt $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Is true that:
$$ \partial_y\mathcal{F}(\phi(\cdot,y))=\mathcal{F}(\partial_y\phi(\cdot,y))?$$
I have no idea. I don't know even to start. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to show that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi(x,y) e^{-ix\cdot\xi}dx
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \phi(x,y) e^{-ix\cdot\xi}dx
.
$$
When can you move a derivative inside an integral?

Comment: Yes, i want move derivative inside integral .

Comment: Under what conditions can a derivative be moved inside an integral?